# selecting entire table when selecting columns - How

Tags: sql, postgresql

Currently i have joined together several tables. now i want to select some columns out of this joined mesh.

my question is: **is it possible to select all columns of a specific table?**

for example:

```
select col1,col4,col7,all_columns.Table1,col9 from (joined tables including Table1)
```

if it is possible, how to implement it

Comment: Have you heard about Table1.*  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is what you want?

```
select col1,
       col4,
       col7,
       Table1.*,
       col9 
from (joined tables including Table1)
```

Comment: hmm, seems easy and promising

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
SELECT ... Table1.*, ... FROM ...
```